# Reverse engineer formula what is 'x'?

Tags: calculus

Formula:
$10000 \times x^{80} = 4369600$

Of which $4369600$ is variable (this one changes a lot)

Therefore I need a formula for what $x$ is?
I can't figure this one out. It sure is challenging for me.

Comment: Can you do with $x=\sqrt[80]{\frac{4.369.600}{ 10.000 }}$ ?

Comment: why do you say 'reverse engineer' ?

Comment: How about using calculator ?? or maybe google ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$10000x^{80} = z$$
gives you the solution
$$x=\sqrt[80]{\frac{z}{10000}}$$

with $z$ being your changing variable for example $z=4369600$

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by the 10,000, then take the 80th root on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
a \, x^y &= b  \\
\log(x^y) &= \log(b/a) \\
\log(x) &= \frac{1}{y} \log(b/a) = z\\
x &= \exp(z)
\end{align}
$$